# Best statistical method to show different performance week over week

Tags: statistical-significance, descriptive-statistics

I am trying to get best statical method to show performance of accumulative revenue by customer compare week over week. Currently I have about over 100 customer charts compare by hour from same day last week vs today.  But what would the best way to show revenue different by hour if I want to put it all in one chart ( assume 100 customers )  ?  would % change below be the best indicator ? or is there a better way to show it in one chart ?

%diff =  (cum current rev / cum previous revenue ) - 1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your goal is to detect unusual activity at an hourly level then build a time series model to predict hourly values. This model may include day-of-the-week effects, holiday effects and trends/level shifts among others. A byproduct of this will be the empirical detection of unusual activity (one-time pulses). This list can be shown foe the last 24 hours and will pinpoint the extra-ordinary activity.

Comment: @IrishStat Thank you, this is great recommendation. This is exactly what I am looking for.